# MessageMapping in Spring 3?

Tags: spring-mvc

I just want to know if the annotation MessageMapping is available in Spring 3? If not can i use it without upgrading to spring 4? I am trying to implement it in liferay 6.1

Thanks,

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: hi i have use ajax as a replacement